# How can we prove the solvability time of a linear program?

Tags: linear-programming, solver, computational-complexity

Given a linear program, by experimentation, I can see that the solver can solve large instances in a few seconds. How can I prove that my LP is in polynomial time, or can we say that it is just by experimentation?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen anyone proving something like that.

Comment: So, How we can say that a given linear program is polynomial-time solvable?

Comment: Linear programming is in P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Ellipsoid_algorithm,_following_Khachiyan All linear programs can be solved in polynomial time